# Cordova | playing a local video in Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, video

i'm struggling with this playing-video-downloaded-from-the-server feature for days now, I would really really appreciate any input on this.

What I have tried so far:

**BASE64 encoding** | this was my main idea at first, getting the string, storing it in SQLite and re-getting it on request. It works great when the file size is lesser than 1.5mb, but crashes the app when it's larger (works great in Chrome though).

**BASE64 to blob** | Due to the crash on video size, I have converted the base64 string to a blob object, and playing the video as a blob. Again, works great in Chrome, but when played in the app the blob object seems to be unreadable or non-playable. As of now i'ms still unsure why blobs are not working in Hybrid Android. I wonder if anyone managed to play a blob video in Android?

**Downloading the video from server** | This sounds like the most simple and elegant solution, downloading the video from the server, storing it in the client's app and playing it from there. Unfortunately, it just doesn't work like that. Though the mp4 file seems readable (presenting the length of the video) but nothing happens when pressing the play button. I know Android has some issues with playing mp4, could be file permissions or encoding issues, the fact that streaming mp4 works great, but when trying to be played from the Android file system it just doesn't work.

I have scattered the net looking for solutions, but have mostly seen the same problems. I'm getting quite lost here so I would really appreciate any words of advice... Much thanks!